# how to run an ajax request on onchange event in select box of flask app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a flask app which have many select boxes. Each select box needs to be  populated with data based on selection in previous select box. I am planning to use ajax for this. Every select box has to be submitted based on `onchange` event. And there is a final form submit button which will be submitted once all select boxes have some value selected.

javascript :

```
    $(function() {
    $('select1').select(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getdata',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

html :

```
<form method="post" action="/getdata">
    Project : <select name="select1" required>
    <option></option>
    {% for p in project %}
    {% for i in p %}
    <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    Task : <select name="category" required>
    <option>----</option>
    {% for p in task %}
    {% for i in p %}
    <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select></div></div>
 <div class="row p-t-20">
<div class="col-md-6">
    Subtask : <select name="category" required>
    <option>----</option>
</select></div>
<div class="col-md-6">   
    Category : <select name="category" required>
    <option>----</option>
</select></div></div></from>
```

flask view :

```
@tt.route('/ti',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])  
def report():
    return render_template('ti.html')
@tt.route('/getdata',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def report():
    project = request.form['select1']
    ~~~ Database codes ~~~~
    return render_template(task=data)
```

How to populate, the database query result into next select box? I also need to do a final submit once all select boxes are selected with some data.

Answer (score 0):

Fistly, make your second and third selectbox have no option.

Then do something likes:

`$(document).on('onchange', '.select1', funtion(){
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/sample.file.name",
        data:$(this).val();
      },
      success:function (res){
      console.log(res); //append this to next selectbox.
      },
     )};
});`

In the /sample.file.name file:

`#Select Project with post param named data`

`#Then print it with the <option> tags`

=> Do this twice to apply it for the second selectbox.

Comment: can i send the output of ajax as a python list to front end and display it in select options using a for loop